SDK/Tools Directory Missing While Setting Up React Native on Windows 11
I'm setting up my development environment on Windows 11 for React Native. During the setup process, I came across instructions to add the SDK/tools folder to my environment variables. However, I can't find any folder named tools in the Android SDK directory.
Is this folder deprecated or replaced in newer SDK versions? If so, which folder(s) should I add to the environment variables for the setup to work correctly?
I checked the Android SDK directory after installing the SDK using Android Studio, but I couldn't find the tools folder.

It should be sufficient to add Sdk/platform-tools to the environment variables.
